# Remove "\n" string from end of certain lines

Tags: sed

How do I remove the string "\n" (not the newline character) from the end of only lines that begin with the string "///"? Thanks.

Example Input:

```
Some text\n

/// Some comment\n
```

Desired Output:

```
Some text\n

/// Some comment
```

I've tried to use

```
sed -i 's/\\n*$//' $1
```

But, it removes all of the trailing "\n" strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a regex address specifier at the front - since your pattern has forward slashes, it's clearer if you use a different expression separator:

```
sed -i '\%^///% s/\\n$//' Input
```

Testing:

```
$ sed '\%^///% s/\\n$//' Input 
Some text\n

/// Some comment
```

If you prefer "leaning toothpicks"

```
sed -i '/^\/\/\// s/\\n$//' Input
```